# «Непубликовавшийся». Правильно, что слитно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

«В случае выдвижения рукописей непубликовавшихся произведений дата создания произведения не имеет значения». Верно написание слитно?

Answer (score -1):

Здесь нет качества (прилагательное), а есть действие (глагольность), поэтому следует писать раздельно.

В Нацкорпусе нет ни одного примера со слитным написанием (в том числе "непубликовавшийся"), зато есть с раздельным: [ссылка1](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F); [ссылка2](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F).

Comment: Так не пойдет, здесь слитное написание. А в ваших примерах есть усилительные или зависимые слова.

Comment: Но здесь нет качества. Не каждое причастие подходит для слитного написания.

Comment: Во всех примерах по ссылкам у причастия есть зависимые слова (никогда, ранее и пр.), поэтому и пишется оно раздельно с "не". Разве всегда следует писать раздельно, если есть действие (глагольность)?

Comment: Да, определённо. Должно быть качество на первом плане.

Comment: Читайте классику.  1. Пишется слитно частица не с полными формами ПРИЧАСТИЯ при которых нет пояснительных слов: невычитанная рукопись; незамеченные опечатки; непроверенные цитаты. http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80

Comment: Но в этих примерах качество на первом плане! Меня смущает тип причастия. Оно страдательное. Это влияет.

Comment: Гугл наотрез отказывается выдавать примеры со слитным написанием.

Comment: По форме (суффикс ВШ)  причастие страдательным не выглядит

Comment: То есть возвратное.

Comment: Таких вроде бы тоже нет.

Comment: В конце *-ся*...

Comment: Это глагол возвратный, а не причастие. Нераспустившийся цветок - слитное написание? Действительное причастие  прошедшего времени.

Comment: http://school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore-wrapper/339d9c16-87f2-4aac-adb9-3f5120ff277c/g1543.htm

Comment: Тоже качество...